# In how many ways $n$ shoes can be arranged in a sequence so that the shoes of one pair do not stand next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

In how many ways $n$ shoes can be arranged in a sequence so that the shoes of one pair do not stand next to each other?

I am sure that it can be done using inclusion-exclusion theorem. Therefore I named an event $A_i = $ shoes of pair $i$ stand next to each other.

Then the question is $|A_1' \cap A_2' \cap A_3' \cap ... \cap A_n'| = 1 - |A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup ... \cup A_n| = |A_1| + |A_2| + \ ... \ - |A_1 \cap A_2| - \ ... \ + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| + \ ...$

We have that: $|A_i| = (n-1) \cdot 2 \cdot (n-2)! $ since we choose one of $n - 1$ places for pair of shoes and then we choose one of $2$ ways to arrange those $2$ shoes. Then we do a permutation of the rest of $n-2$ shoes.

We then have: $|A_i \cap A_j| = (n-1) \cdot 2 \cdot (n-2-1) \cdot 2 \cdot (n-2 - 2)! $

And so we see that the answer is equal to:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n |A_i| - \sum_{ 1 \leq i < j \leq n}^n |A_i \cap A_j| + \sum_{ 1 \leq i < j < k \leq n}^n |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k|- ... + (-1)^{n+1}|A_i \cap ... \cap  A_n|$$

That is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n 2(n-1)! - \sum_{ 1 \leq i < j \leq n}^n 4(n-1)(n-3)! + \sum_{ 1 \leq i < j < k \leq n}^n 8(n-1)(n-3)(n-5)! - ... + (-1)^{n+1} 2k(n-1)!!$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Clarification question: Please, add even natural number $n$ on question statement

Comment: Answer suggestion: think on how to place each pair side by side and subtract by the number of arrangements $n!$.

Comment: Assuming you only take $k$ shoes, taking one shoe form each pair, there are $2^k$ ways to choose one shoe from each pair. And there are $n \choose k$ ways to choose them. Thus ${n \choose k} \cdot 2^k$ choices .

Comment: Should be $n$ pairs of shoes. See OEIS [A007060](https://oeis.org/A007060)

Comment: I think you meant to write $(-1)^{n+1} 2^k (n-1)!!$. Also, you have to somehow choose shoes that will be in the wrong pair.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have n **pairs** of shoes instead of n shoes.

From the principle of inclusion and exclusion, we get
$$
\sum_{p=0}^{n}(-1)^{p}{\binom{n}{p}}2^{p} (2n-p)!
$$
where $p$ is the number of bad pairs, meaning that two shoes from the same pair are next to each other.

We choose the bad pairs in $\binom{n}{p}$ ways, and then, as you wrote, each pair has two ordering possibilities, i.e., $2^p$.
Finally, we have to arrange everything into a sequence. In total, we have $2n$ shoes, but we know that $p$ shoes definitely stand next to their pair, so there are $(2n-p)$ elements to permute giving $(2n-p)!$.

But I don't know how to simplify this sum.